# Springboot 2.1.x Webflux functional endpoints - How to perform input validation?

Tags: validation, spring-webflux

I am trying to integrate validation in this code, but it fails without any error (just a blank page being returned):

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class EthereumAccountController implements ClarityControllerMono {

    private final Pipeline queryPipeline;

    private final Pipeline commandPipeline;

    private final Web3jService web3;

    private final RequestHandler requestHandler;

    public EthereumAccountController(@Qualifier("queryPipelinr") Pipeline queryPipeline, @Qualifier("commandPipelinr") Pipeline commandPipeline, Web3jService web3, RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        this.queryPipeline = queryPipeline;
        this.commandPipeline = commandPipeline;
        this.web3 = web3;
        this.requestHandler = requestHandler;
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> createAccount(ServerRequest serverRequest) {


        return requestHandler.requireValidBody(body -> getJsonErrsResp("testtttt"), serverRequest, AccountRequestDTO.class);


    }

}
```

```
public interface ClarityControllerMono {



    default Mono<ServerResponse> getJsonSuccessResp (Object object) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        result.put("status", "success");
        result.put("data", object);

        return ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(toJSON(result)), String.class));
    }


    default Mono<ServerResponse> getJsonErrsResp (Object object) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        result.put("status", "error");
        result.put("message", object);

        return ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(toJSON(result)), String.class));
    }

    private String toJSON(Object object) {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return Unchecked.function(objectMapper::writeValueAsString).apply(object);
        }

}
```

[Repo here](https://github.com/Deviad/clarity/blob/feature/wip_validation/clarity-transaction-dispatcher/src/main/java/com/clarity/transactiondispatcher/web/controller/EthereumAccountController.java?fbclid=IwAR36iVyfZZ8RwwwTKgCOQxYFLZgnzOhbf38K3vW-pJVHm5ZqFrBGzrFomFc)

This is where the code fails

```
@Component
public class RequestHandler {

    private final Validator validator;

    public RequestHandler(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public <BODY> Mono<ServerResponse> requireValidBody(
            Function<Mono<BODY>, Mono<ServerResponse>> block,
            ServerRequest request, Class<BODY> bodyClass) {

        return request
                .bodyToMono(bodyClass)
                .flatMap(
                        body -> validator.validate(body).isEmpty()
                                ? block.apply(Mono.just(body))
                                : ServerResponse.unprocessableEntity().build()
                );
    }
}
```

This is the repo where I found this interesting solution that I want to implement (the bit of code where it's failing)
https://github.com/jeroenbellen/Validate-functional-endpoints-in-Spring/blob/master/src/main/java/foo/bar/springfunctionalwebvalidation/controller/RequestHandler.java

Thank you in advance.

EDIT

```
    public <BODY> Mono<ServerResponse> requireValidBody(
            Function<Mono<BODY>, Mono<ServerResponse>> block,
            ServerRequest request, Class<BODY> bodyClass) {
        Hooks.onOperatorDebug();
        return request
                .bodyToMono(bodyClass)
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                .flatMap(
                        body -> {
                            log.info("Emptyness" +validator.validate(body).isEmpty() + "");
                           return validator.validate(body).isEmpty()
                                    ? block.apply(Mono.just(body))
                                    : ServerResponse.unprocessableEntity().build();
                        }
                ).doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

doOnError does not out put anything.

Comment: `.body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(toJSON(result))` can you try changing this to just `.body(toJSON(result))`

Comment: Basically the compiler screams that it needs a BodyInserter in that place. Be aware that the exception is thrown somehow at the flatmap in RequestHandler. However even executing Hooks.onOperatorDebug() as I read in a tutorial, I cannot catch the exception and print it.

Comment: sorry i meant to `.syncBody(toJSON(result))`

Comment: you can chain on a `.doOnError(throwable -> { ... })` and see what error you get

Comment: .syncBody(toJSON(result)) seams to be fine, however the code is still failing and doOnError doesn't output anything. :(

Comment: but when debugging do you reach the flatmap statement?

Comment: It basically stops before the flatmap with no reason

Comment: `block.apply(Mono.just(body))` this part also looks weird to me, you are passing in a mono, and not the body

Comment: To be honest many things have changed since a few versions like Spring Validator abstract class, which is not anymore a class but an interface. And for some reason Intellij cannot even find the implementation of that bodyToMono function. Before it was kind of "easy", at least there was an approach to follow, which is this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-functional-endpoints-validation